# elements being copied along a list in python

Tags: python, list, class

I have a list of lists called `hab` acting as a 2D array. In this list of lists I am storing elements of a class called `loc` which is why I am not using a numpy array (it's not storing numbers).

I want to fill each element with a randomly picked 'loc' by looping through each element. However it seems that whenever I get to the end of a row, the program takes the final row element and puts it in all the other elements in that row. This means that I end up with the list of lists looking like this:

```
3 3 3 3 3  
1 1 1 1 1  
2 2 2 2 2  
2 2 2 2 2  
4 4 4 4 4
```

when actually I want all these numbers to be random (this is printing out a specific trait of each `loc` which is why it is numbers).

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
allspec=[] # a list of species
for i in range(0,initialspec):
    allspec.append(species(i)) # make a new species with new index
    print 'index is',allspec[i].ind, 'pref is', allspec[i].pref
hab=[[0]*xaxis]*yaxis
respect = randint(0,len(allspec)-1)
for j in range(0,yaxis):
    for k in range (0,xaxis):
        respect=randint(0,len(allspec)-1)
        print 'new species added at ',k,j,' is ', allspec[respect].ind
        hab[k][j]=loc(k,j,random.random(),allspec[respect])
        print 'to confirm, this is ', hab[k][j].spec.ind

    for k in range (0,xaxis):
        print hab[k][j].spec.ind

printgrid(hab,xaxis,yaxis)
print 'element at 1,1', hab[1][1].spec.ind
```

Within the loop, I am confirming that the element I have created is what I want it to be with the line `print 'to confirm, this is ', hab[k][j].spec.ind` and it is fine at this point. It is only when that loop is exited that it somehow fills every element on the row with the same thing. I don't understand!

Comment: You should use [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) here, or possibly even [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: Can you show your `printgrid` function?  It's very possible that you're actually creating the list right but then printing it wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
hab=[[0]*xaxis]*yaxis
```

As a result of the above statement, `hab` consists of `yaxis` references *to the same list*:

```
In [6]: map(id, hab)
Out[6]: [18662824, 18662824, 18662824]
```

When you modify `hab[k][j]`, all other `hab[][j]` change too:

```
In [10]: hab
Out[10]: [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

In [11]: hab[0][0] = 42

In [12]: hab
Out[12]: [[42, 0], [42, 0], [42, 0]]
```

To fix, use

```
hab=[[0]*xaxis for _ in range(yaxis)]
```

Now each entry of `hab` refers to a separate list:

```
In [8]: map(id, hab)
Out[8]: [18883528, 18882888, 18883448]

In [14]: hab
Out[14]: [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

In [15]: hab[0][0] = 42

In [16]: hab
Out[16]: [[42, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thankyou! Can you tell me why my way of defining it doesn't work?

Comment: @CatherineGeorgia: Please see the expanded answer.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer explains what is wrong, but I want to offer a much clearer implementation using features of Python you may not be aware of.

```
import random
from pprint import pprint

class species(object):
    def __init__(self, ind):
        self.ind = ind
        self.perf = ind

def makespecies(n):
    # using list comprehensions, we don't need a for-loop
    # we could also have said `map(species, range(n))`
    return [species(i) for i in range(n)]


def makegrid(w, h, species):
    # rather than initialize empty lists, we create a new list
    # for each row as we go. This avoids the bug in your code
    # while also being much easier to read.
    return [[random.choice(species) for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]

def printgrid(grid, attr):
    pprint([[getattr(e, attr, None)  for e in row] for row in grid])

speclist = makespecies(10)
grid = makegrid(5,5,speclist)
printgrid(grid, 'ind')
```

This will print something like:

```
[[5, 8, 6, 8, 9],
 [9, 3, 3, 1, 3],
 [3, 8, 1, 5, 5],
 [7, 4, 7, 1, 7],
 [4, 3, 3, 1, 9]]
```

Note also that if you are working with large arrays or doing matrix-oriented operations on them, you should consider using numpy. You can create a "master" nested array (like this one) which has your species objects as raw data, and then [`vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) it to numpy arrays for numerical operations.

Comment: That does look a lot more elegant than the stuff I have, thanks very much.